# Intersection not narrowing union properly

Tags: typescript

I have the following use case: I have a union of Foo and Bar. Both Foo and Bar have a type property, each with their own enum values "foo" and "bar". In addition, they each have a payload property, with Foo's being a string and Bar's being a number.

```
enum Types {
    FOO = "foo",
    BAR = "bar"
}

interface Foo {
    type: Types.FOO;
    payload: string;
}

interface Bar {
    type: Types.BAR;
    payload: number;
}

type Union = Foo | Bar;
```

Now, I tried to narrow the union using an intersection where I define the type like this:

```
// Does not pass type check because payload must be a string
const baz: Union & { type: Types.FOO } = {
  type: Types.FOO,
  payload: 42
}
```

This does not pass the type check (as I did expect), since payload is a number, but should be a string when the type is FOO.

On the other hand, this compiles (As I did expect):

```
// Passes type check
const baz: Union & {type: Types.FOO} = {
    type: Types.FOO,
    payload: "foobar"
}
```

Now I have a function handleFoo which I type like this:

```
function handleFoo(foo: Union & {type: Types.FOO}) {
    // payload is string | number
    console.log(foo.payload)
    if (foo.type === Types.FOO) {
        // payload is still string | number??
        console.log(foo.payload)
    }
}
```

TS tells me that payload is a string | number union. But at the same time, the type is impossible to construct with payload being a number. In addition, even if I check that the type is FOO, it still does not narrow the type of foo down.

On the other hand, if I do it like this, I get the expected narrowing after the FOO check.

```
function handleFoo2(foo: Union) {
    console.log(foo.payload) // payload is string | number
    if (foo.type === Types.FOO) {
        // payload is string
        console.log(foo.payload)
    }
}
```

The second approach (and the general type check in handleFoo) is impractical for me, because that check is already performed in the caller of handleFoo.

Is this a bug, or simply some kind of misunderstanding of type narrowing?

Is there any way to solve this, or should I file a bug with the TypeScript team?

Answer (score 1):

try `Extract<Union, {type: Types.FOO}>` instead of `Union & { type: Types.FOO }`

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get this (I have not been able to figure it out)?

> TS tells me that payload is a string | number union. But at the same time, the type is impossible to construct with payload being a number.

I put together bits of your code, when I check the types of the payloads that can be assigned to the respective functions filtered by type, the end result is that I have a discreet "string" or "number" type, I have not been able to get "string | number".

So, if what you want is a generic handler for "Union" types, as long as they are agnostic to the type of payload Typescript will warn you if on your code you have incompatible types. Do note I added a function that has no checks (kind of like your handleFoo2 without the if check), and it does not have any issues dealing with both types as long as they are declared consistently (i.e. you don not pass an object Foo with a numeric payload or a Bar Object with a string payload).

I put together an example that can be run on Typescript Playground where all functions do work. For convenience I also copied the source below. [Typescript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Types%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FOO%20%3D%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BAR%20%3D%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.FOO%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.BAR%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Union%20%3D%20Foo%20%7C%20Bar%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Union%20%26%20%7B%20type%3A%20Types.BAR%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.BAR%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%205%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%3A%20Union%20%26%20%7B%20type%3A%20Types.FOO%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.FOO%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%22foobar%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fooUnion%3A%20Union%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.FOO%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20%22foobar%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20barUnion%3A%20Union%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Types.BAR%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%205%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleFoo(foo%3A%20Union%20%26%20%7Btype%3A%20Types.FOO%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(typeof%20foo.payload)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20alert%20displays%20%22string%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(foo.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20Types.FOO)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(foo.payload)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleFoo2(foo%3A%20Union)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(typeof%20foo.payload)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20alert%20displays%20%22string%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(foo.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20Types.FOO)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(foo.payload)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleUnion(union%3A%20Union)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(typeof%20union.payload)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(union.payload)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleBar(foo%3A%20Union%20%26%20%7Btype%3A%20Types.BAR%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(typeof%20foo.payload)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20alert%20displays%20%22number%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(foo.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20Types.BAR)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(foo.payload)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleBar2(foo%3A%20Union)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(typeof%20foo.payload)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20alert%20displays%20%22number%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(foo.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20Types.FOO)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(foo.payload)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AhandleFoo(foo)%3B%0D%0AhandleFoo2(foo)%3B%0D%0AhandleBar(bar)%3B%0D%0AhandleBar2(bar)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AhandleFoo(fooUnion)%3B%0D%0AhandleFoo2(fooUnion)%3B%0D%0AhandleBar(barUnion)%3B%0D%0AhandleBar2(barUnion)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AhandleUnion(fooUnion)%3B%0D%0AhandleUnion(barUnion)%3B)

```
enum Types {
    FOO = "foo",
    BAR = "bar"
}

interface Foo {
    type: Types.FOO;
    payload: string;
}

interface Bar {
    type: Types.BAR;
    payload: number;
}

type Union = Foo | Bar;


const bar: Union & { type: Types.BAR } = {
    type: Types.BAR,
    payload: 5
};


const foo: Union & { type: Types.FOO } = {
    type: Types.FOO,
    payload: "foobar"
};

const fooUnion: Union = {
    type: Types.FOO,
    payload: "foobar"
}

const barUnion: Union = {
    type: Types.BAR,
    payload: 5
}

function handleFoo(foo: Union & {type: Types.FOO}) {
    alert(typeof foo.payload);
    // alert displays "string"
    if (foo.type === Types.FOO) {
        alert(foo.payload);
    }
}

function handleFoo2(foo: Union) {
    alert(typeof foo.payload);
    // alert displays "string"
    if (foo.type === Types.FOO) {
        alert(foo.payload)
    }
}

function handleUnion(union: Union) {
    alert(typeof union.payload);
    alert(union.payload);
}

function handleBar(foo: Union & {type: Types.BAR}) {
    alert(typeof foo.payload);
    // alert displays "number"
    if (foo.type === Types.BAR) {
        alert(foo.payload);
    }
}

function handleBar2(foo: Union) {
    alert(typeof foo.payload);
    // alert displays "number"
    if (foo.type === Types.FOO) {
        alert(foo.payload)
    }
}

handleFoo(foo);
handleFoo2(foo);
handleBar(bar);
handleBar2(bar);

handleFoo(fooUnion);
handleFoo2(fooUnion);
handleBar(barUnion);
handleBar2(barUnion);

handleUnion(fooUnion);
handleUnion(barUnion);
```